# Accessibility UITableView scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I am trying to put a custom tableview cell implementation and have 3 different kind of cells lined up in a tableview. if i simply add accessibility label to each and every table view cell it works fine without issues, there are 6 items and the scroll happens automatically when the left the right swipe is tried.

but the scrolling is not happening when i custom implement a reading order in the table view cell, the cell is never selected and the scroll doesnt happen for 4th cell onwards, it simply stays there and reading pointer alone keeps moving.

what can be done to make the table view scroll little bit once the focus on the fourth cell i got ?